# Largest palindrome product - Ruby

Tags: ruby, algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Como deixar esse código mais rápido? Ele funciona, mas não rápido o suficiente.

```
#!/bin/ruby

def isPalin(mul)
  if mul.to_s == mul.to_s.reverse then
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

def lp(n)
  arr = []

  for a1 in (100..999)
    for a2 in (100..999)
      mul = a1*a2
      break if mul > n
      if mul <= n then
        arr.push(mul) if isPalin(mul)
      end
    end
  end

  arr.sort!
  puts arr[arr.length-1]

end


t = gets.strip.to_i
for a0 in (0..t-1)
  n = gets.strip.to_i

  lp(n)
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Por favor traduza sua pergunta, este é o SO em português.

Comment: traduzido logo abaixo, sorry!

Comment: henrique, o campo abaixo é para respostas apenas, o correto é você editar a pergunta com a tradução.

Answer (score 0):

O duplo loop for faz trabalho dobrado: n1 * n2 == n2 * n1. Use o índice de fora no loop de dentro, para evitar a repetição.

`(100..999).each do |n1|
   (n1..999).each do |n2|
      mul = n1 * n2
      if mul <= n 
         arr << mul if palindromo?(mul.to_s)
      else
         break
      end
   end
end`

`each` é um método de Enumerable, herdado por Array. Veja na documentação.

A função isPalin pode ser tornada mais simples, começando por cortar o `if ... then true else false`:

`def isPalin(mul)
   return mul.to_s == mul.to_s.reverse 
end`

Até o `return` final pode ser cortado, deixando apenas a expressão, porque a função retornará o último valor calculado.

Se você presumir que o valor já é uma string, pode usar o fato de que strings têm seus caracteres indexados, e admitem índices negativos:

`def palindromo?(s)
   tam = s.size
   return true if tam < 2
   return (0..(tam/2)).all? { |i| s[i] == s[tam - i - 1] }
end`

`all?` é outro método de Enumerable: retorna true se todos os elementos do enumerável retornam true quando aplicados ao bloco.